# Why is this hyperlink not working in my php code

Tags: php

```
    <?php
$author_ID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$username = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_ID);
$author_url = esc_url( get_author_posts_url($author_ID) );
?>
<div class="author-box">
<figure class="author-box-avatar">
<?php echo get_avatar($author_ID, 65); ?>
</figure>
< a href="<?php echo $author_url; ?>"> <?php echo $username; ?> </a>
</div>
```

It displays something like this author url and after that the username brad in this example. What i am trying to do is hyperlink brad.

```
mysite.com/author-name-brad  Brad
```

Comment: What's the actual rendered HTML and what's the value of `$author_url` and `$username`? And is the space in `< a` a typo in your example or in your real code?

Comment: I've rolled back the edits to this post; the first editor had edited the code so that it removed what the OP has identified as the problem. This is why you don't edit code in questions!

Answer (score 2):

There was a whitespace in your html tag `< a` remove it

```
<?php
$author_url = "t.php";
$username = "ik";
?>

<a href="<?php echo $author_url; ?>"> <?php echo $username; ?> </a>
```

this echos hyperlink ik

Comment: It was the white space. Thanks